# A good tool for formatting partition aside Gparted

Tags: partitioning, format

There is a good and quite easy to use tool for format partition, especially with nfts fs, aside Gparted which with I've had some issues?

Comment: Wha issues are you having ewith Gparted?

Answer (score 0):

`cfdisk` is one good tool tool for partitioning. Run in command-line as `sudo cfdisk`

Answer (score 0):

The gnome-disk-utility should be installed by default, which gives you an simple interface for formating your partitions, external- and flashdrives.

Otherwise install it with

```
sudo apt-get install gnome-disk-utility
```

Afterwards you should find it as "disk management" (hopefully, translation guessed, I am on a german system) in your dash or menu.

Hope this helps.
Good Luck!